# DJANGO how to handle two forms in one form tag

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two form Postform and Fileform and i am placing both forms in one  tag. but when i press submit button nothing happens. and i also made file field not required but it is still not working. but when i give input to both forms only then it work.
i want if file is not present it should work and just save post form.

> form.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    choice = (
        ('post','post'),
        ('anouncement','anouncement'),
        ('question', 'question')
        )
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'mdl-textfield__input','id':'s1'}))
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'mdl-textfield__input','id':'sample5','rows':'3'}))
    post_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choice, widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class':'mdl-selectfield__select', 'id':'post_type'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
            "post_type",

        ]

class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True,'class':'none','id':'file_input_file','required':'False'}), required = False )
    class Meta:
        model = file
        fields = [
            "file"
        ]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(FileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # there's a `fields` property now
        self.fields['file'].required = False
```

> views.py:

```
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    fileForm = FileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
    context.update({'form':form, 'fileform':fileForm})
    print(fileForm.is_valid())
    if form.is_valid() and fileForm.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        slug = create_slug(instance)
        instance.slug = slug
        instance.save()
        print(request.FILES)
        if request.FILES :
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
                print(f)
                file.objects.create(Post = instance, file=f)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s/post/%s/'%(request.user.username,slug))
```

> template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                        <span style="display: inline-flex;">
                            <div class="file_input_div">
                                <div class="file_input">
                                    <label class="image_input_button mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
                                        <i class="material-icons">file_upload</i>
                                        {{ fileform.file}}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div id="file_input_text_div" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield textfield-demo">
                                    <input class="file_input_text mdl-textfield__input" type="text" disabled readonly id="file_input_text" />
                                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="file_input_text"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored align-right" name="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
                        </span>
                    </form>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is there a good reason not to just add a FileField to the Post class? You could make that field not required.